# C++ proper structure initialization

Tags: c++, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm sorry to ask another newbie question, but google could'nt quite help me (or maybe I just didn't understand it).

I'm trying to code a class that is capable of storing some simple connection data. My early concept looks like the following:

```
struct connectionElement{
 string ip;
 SOCKET soc;
};

class ConnectionData{
 private:
  vector<connectionElement> connections;

 public:
  ConnectionData();
  ~ConnectionData();

  void addConnection(string ip, SOCKET soc);
};

void ConnectionData::addConnection(string ip, SOCKET soc) {
 connectionElement newElement;
 newElement.ip = ip;
 newElement.soc = soc;
 connections.push_back(newElement);
 return;
}
```

Now I've read that objects being initialized without the use of *new* will be delocated once the code reaches the end of scope. So since I'm a java guy and don't know shi* about memory allocation, I was wondering what the correct way'd be to to initialize the new *connectionElement* in *addConnection()*.

Do I have to use *new* in order to prevent the data from being deleted or does the compiler assume that a stored structure might be accessed again later on? And if I use the *new* operator do I have to delete all the objects manually before the thread terminates or does that happen automatically?

Comment: I think the better question is does the vector class copy the object or assign a pointer to it. If it dynamically copies, then no need to worry.

Comment: Looks fine to me.  In your case, since your `connectionElement` consists only a string (which manages its own memory) and a SOCKET (integer), there's nothing for you to worry about.

Comment: @selbie so are there actually data types that I'd have to initialize using new in this case? And how do I know which ones require me to do so?

Comment: This doesn’t address the question, but `connectionElement` should have a constructor that takes an ip and soc. With that, `addConnection` becomes `connectionElement newElement(ip, soc); connections.push_back(newConnection);`. Or even `connections.push_back(connectionElement(ip, soc));`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do I have to use new in order to prevent the data from being deleted or does the compiler assume that a stored structure might be accessed again later on?

No, in your snippet, the class `ConnectionData` owns its data member `connections`, and the elements in the vector are stored by value. Hence, `connections` is existant as long as its owning class instance exists:

```
void someFunctionInYourProgram()
{
    ConnectionData example{};

    example.addConection(/* ... */);

    // do stuff with the ConnectionData instance and its connections

    void doMoreStuffWith(example);

 } // Now, example went out of scope, everything is automatically cleaned up.
```

> And if I use the new operator do I have to delete all the objects manually before the thread terminates or does that happen automatically?

If you allocate objects with `new` and don't pass the raw pointer returned to some smart poiter taking care of its deletion, you must indeed manually clean it up with `delete`. But there shouldn't be too many situation where this applies, as `std::shared_ptr` and `std::unique_ptr` are there to the rescue, and they ship with `std::make_shared` and `std::make_unique`, which even makes it obsolete to manually invoke the `new` operator.

One last note on this snippet

```
connectionElement newElement;
newElement.ip = ip;
newElement.soc = soc;
connections.push_back(newElement);
```

You can simplify this to

```
connections.push_back({ip, soc});
```

which might save a copy construction (if not already optimized out by the compiler).

Answer (score 1):

Your code works!

```
vector.push_back()
```

Copies the object, so a copy of the entire structure will exist in the connections vector.